# Content-Security-Policy: Refused to execute inline script on lite server

Tags: angular, lite-server

I am following angular's best practice in order to make PWA. After making production build (`ng built --prod --aot`). I am also running from dist on `localhost`: `npm run dev` (`"dev": "lite-server"`).
When the browser load I get an error in the console:

`Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-EzX1NiGgmo59Hi8wZ/thoAxnVbkTfzIAgnVddwzUO3Y='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

I tried to add to index.html:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Gal, did you find a solution to your question? I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Please make true like this in router module

```
RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: true})
```

Comment: That's a perfect answer bro.. worked for me... !! Thanks. The error is clear though...!! How did you find it??